# How to skip login if already logged in - log in with google - android

Tags: android, google-signin

I want to skip the login activity if I'm already logged in. The main idea is, the first time I open the app I have to see the login activity since I'm not logged in but if I log in and after I close the app once I open the app again I want to see the menu, not the logging Activity.

I tried to look online but I don't understand very well. 
I'm new to android so I try to understand as much as I can. Below I will let my code. By the way, this doesn't work and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    name =findViewById(R.id.name);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    if(mGoogleSignInClient == null ){
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signIn();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    fetchLocation();
    statusCheck();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this, whenever you open your app

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = new GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity);
```

You can get the session of last login, if its not null i.e

```
if(account!=null && !account.isExpired())
   String email =account.email.toString();
```

I have translated it from Kotlin, there could be little bit changes for declaration.

Comment: I used what you told me but I just need to use the (account!=null) part inside the if case. Thank you